# Can i use a Lightning Web Component from another Package/Namespace?

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

Im developing a couple of components and i have 2 different namespaces (for project reasons), i tried to use the component form namespace b on my component on namespace a although i can save and it compiles fine, when the page loads i get this error

> Attempting to reference cross-namespace module gui_utl-fileExplorer in
>   gui_tkt-workOrderFileExplorer

I know with Aura components you can define access="global" but i cant find the way to do it on LWC if there is.

BTW: My Both my components are exposed true

Comment: whats the name of your components and the namespace of both the components?

Comment: The component i want to use fileExplorer in gui_utl namespace and i want to use it from workOrderFileExplorer in gui_tkt namespace

Comment: Please vote on this idea, hopefully it will get some attention.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CaKLQA0

Answer (score 8):

Based on this document, it seems like you can't:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc

> **Limits** A custom Lightning web component can’t access a Lightning web component or module in a custom namespace. It can access Lightning
>   web components and modules only in the c and lightning namespaces.

Comment: Update Dec 2021 - in theory the new Lightning Web Security WILL allow this to be possible:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_security_intro.htm&type=5&release=234

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer was in the comment.

[Actually, if you enable `Use Lightning Web Security (beta) for Lightning web components.` in Session settings, it works.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&release=234&id=release-notes.rn_lwc_security_intro.htm)

Thanks @BritishBoyinDC for his comment.

Comment: Yes, this works but it contains some limitation for now. It is best to wait for Lightning Web Security becomes GA.

Comment: @patlatus: I have tried accessing the LWC from a managed package in my org. There are 2 different use cases,

1.) In the first case the managed package is deployed in Sandbox environment and accessing LWC of Managed package in my custom component is working after enabling lightning web security.

2.) When the package is deployed in developer edition, this does not work. I see an error that states, `Attempting to reference cross-namespace module in custom component Callback failed:`

Does this not work in dev or production environments?

Comment: I believe it worked in developer edition envs, did you save the LWS and clear cache and made hard reload of your component?